# Custom Compose LazyVerticalGrid

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In your opinion, how can I make a list like this with Compose?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvQrz.png

I tried all the methods like FlowColumn ,FlowRow, LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid or other custom classes, but I did not achieve anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a lazyColumn -> items than a row
in the row check if the item is > 1 (not first item)
something like this

```
 LazyColumn {
        items(data.chunked(2)) { rowItems ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(8.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Text(text = rowItems[0])
                }

                if (rowItems.size > 1) {
               
                } else {
                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a dynamic list and I can't say that it only takes the first item

Comment: just an example, you can make it random or specific items